# How to search the first occurrence from two different tstringlist

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

I need to compare two different lists that contain the name of the folder that needs to be copied from a path (`chosenDirectory` from `FOpenDialog.FileName`) to my local repository (`PathLocalRepo = ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+LOCAL_REPOSITORY_01`).

The problem is that I need to check if a folder name is already present in my local repository, and if it is present then I need to escape my loop and continue with the next value.

This is my code:

```
for N := 0 to ListFoldersImported.Count-1 do
begin
  for Y := 0 to ListFoldersLocalRepository.Count-1 do
  begin
    if MatchStr(ExtractFileName(ListFoldersImported[N]), ExtractFileName(ListFoldersLocalRepository[Y])) = True then
    begin
      FlagFound := True;
      Break;
    end else
    begin
      FlagFound := False;
      ListOfFoldersThatNeedsToBeCopied.Add(ListFoldersImported[N]);
    end;
  end;
  if FlagFound = False then
    TDirectory.Copy(chosenDirectory,PathLocalRepo)
end;
```

This code won't stop my loop if it finds the first occurrence, and it does not continue to compare [Y] with next [N] value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need the next logic:

```
for N:= 0 to ListFoldersImported.Count-1 do
begin
    FlagFound := False;
    for Y:= 0 to ListFoldersLocalRepository.Count-1 do
    begin
          if MatchStr(ExtractFileName(ListFoldersImported[N]),ExtractFileName(ListFoldersLocalRepository[Y])) = True then
          begin
              FlagFound := True;
              Break;
          end;
    end;
    if not FlagFound then
    begin
       ListOfFoldersThatNeedsToBeCopied.Add(ListFoldersImported[N]);
       TDirectory.Copy(chosenDirectory,PathLocalRepo);
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: it works very well !!! My mistake was where close the nested for loop to compare fixed value from left and right value change every time